# Don't understand cause of this TypeError

Tags: python, function, class, typeerror

Can someone help me figure this out the cause if this TypeError?

```
class bmi:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = 0
        self.height = 0

    def calc_bmi(self,weight,height):
        self.bm = self.weight /self.height * self.height
        return self.bm

def main():
    obj = bmi()
    weight = float(input("Enter weight"))
    height = float(input("Enter height"))

    result =  bmi.calc_bmi(weight,height)
    print(f"Your bmi is {result}")

main()
```

Error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File bmi_calculator.py, 
    line 21, in <module> main()
  File bmi_calculator.py, 
    line 18, in main
    result =  bmi.calc_bmi(weight,height)
TypeError: calc_bmi() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'
```

Comment: What went wrong? Was there an error (then post it). Did a calculation not work like you want?

Comment: And folks, lets not just jump directly to "close" without helping the poster fill in details.

Comment: This class only does one thring... so why make it a class at all?

Comment: You're getting a `TypeError` on the `result =  bmi.calc_bmi(weight,height)` line because you're calling the method with the **class**, not the instance of it that was created — you need to change it to: `result =  obj.calc_bmi(weight,height)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: There is a class design issue here. What do you want this class to do? You initialize height and weight when the class is created, but then have them as parameters to calc_bmi. Don't do both. If this this is supposed to hold bmi for a single person, initialize height and weight in `__init__` and then make a `@property` named `bmi` that calculates the value when referenced.

Comment: I'm a beginner in programming in python and I'm just following the exercise here ok. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

**You have two issues here.**

**1)** A class is meant to create as an object, so do obj.calc_bmi(weight,height)

**2)** self.wieght and self.height need to be set by the values passed in

Here's a working solution

```
class bmi:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = 0
        self.height = 0
    def calc_bmi(self,weight,height):
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height
        if self.height<=0:
            print("!!!DIVISON BY ZERO ERROR!!!")
            return None
        self.bm = self.weight /self.height * self.height
        return self.bm

def main():
    obj = bmi()
    weight = float(input("Enter weight"))
    height = float(input("Enter height"))
    
    result =  obj.calc_bmi(weight,height)
    print(f"Your bmi is {result}")

main()
```

Watch this video and you will understand everything (https://youtu.be/JeznW_7DlB0)